# Who remove my iOS application?

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification

Based on [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391351/how-to-know-all-devices-tokens-to-send-push-notification-apns-in-a-loop#comment7491681_6391389) by saying that I can only send push notifications to devices that have installed my application (so my certificate is not blacklisted from Apple), how do I know who removed the application so I can remove the device token from my database?

Is there any other solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using an apple service to check if a push notification id is still valid, you can read about it [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingWIthAPS/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW3)